# How to update a row with a substring of a string in that particular row?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I need an SQLite statement for this example:

There is a path with filename like:

```
/home/user/files/filename.ext
```

Now I need to update all rows to this:

```
/home/user/files/filename/filename.ext
```

The filename without extension needs to be inserted between `files/` and `filename.ext`

Comment: i'm totally new to this. the database is an sqlite file. i could update each row by hand, but there are 600+ rows :( and i googled a lot but didn't find a hint. maybe i'm searching with the wrong keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MySQL:

```
update filelist set filepath= CONCAT(substr(filepath,1,17),right(left(filepath,length(filepath)-4),length(filepath)-21),'/',right(left(filepath,length(filepath)-4),length(filepath)-21),substr(filepath,-4))
```

For SQLite:

```
update filelist
set filepath= substr(filepath,1,17)||substr(filepath,length(filepath)-3,21-length(filepath))||'/'||substr(filepath,length(filepath)-3,21-length(filepath))||substr(filepath,-4)
```

Hope this work for you.

Use stuff function if you use MS SQL to insert text into text:

```
update filelist
set filepath=stuff(filepath,17,1,'gggg')
;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is an sqlite file. maybe i find something like the stuff function.

Comment: The `STUFF` function is SQL Server, not MySQL.

Comment: Thank you so much Jahirul Islam Bhuiyan! It works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the in-build [REPLACE()](http://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) function to get the desired result.

> The replace(X,Y,Z) function returns a string formed by substituting
>   string Z for every occurrence of string Y in string X. The BINARY
>   collating sequence is used for comparisons. If Y is an empty string
>   then return X unchanged. If Z is not initially a string, it is cast to
>   a UTF-8 string prior to processing.

```
UPDATE table_name
SET pathColumn = replace(pathColumn, '/home/user/files/', '/home/user/files/filename/')
-- Where column = some condition ---- THIS IS OPTIONAL, if you dont want to modify all rows
```

you can add the WHERE clause, if sub set of tables rows needs to be modified